# MYSQL Count of duplicate records with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get count of duplicate data, but my query doesn't work correctly.

Every user should have one dev_id but when other user will have this same dev_id I want to know this

Table for example:

```
 dev_id     user_id
 ------------------
  111           1
  111           1
  222           2
  111           2
  333           3
```

Should result:

```
  user_id       qu
  ------------------
    1           1
    2           1
    3           0
```

This is my query

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
    (SELECT Count(DISTINCT t2.dev_id)
         FROM reports t2
         WHERE t2.user_id != t1.user_id
         AND t2.dev_id = t1.dev_id
    ) AS qu
FROM       reports t1
GROUP BY   t1.user_id
```

Comment: Does not work correctly how? What does it do?

Comment: Please be clearer on what you mean by "duplicate data".

Comment: Every user should have one dev_id but when other user will have this same dev_id I want to know this

Comment: You're correlating on `dev_id` which is not an aggregated column. Your query is fundamentally broken even though MySQL allows you to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Let start from simple.

First you need get unique user_id/dev id combinations

```
select distinct dev_id,user_id from reports
```

Result will be

```
 dev_id     user_id
 ------------------
  111           1
  222           2
  111           2
  333           3
```

After that you should get number of different user_id per dev_id

```
select dev_id,c from (
  SELECT
    dev_id,
    count(*)-1 AS c
  FROM
    (select distinct user_id,dev_id from reports) as fixed_reports
  GROUP BY dev_id
                     ) as counts
```

Result of such query will be

```
 dev_id     c
 -----------------
  111           1
  222           0
  333           0
```

Now you should show users which have such dev_id. For that you should join such dev_id list with table from step1(which show which one user_id,dev_id pairs exist)

```
select distinct fixed_reports2.user_id,counts.c from (
  SELECT
    dev_id,
    count(*)-1 AS c
  FROM
    (select distinct user_id,dev_id from reports) as fixed_reports
  GROUP BY dev_id
                                             ) as counts
      join 
    (select distinct user_id,dev_id from reports) as fixed_reports2
      on fixed_reports2.dev_id=counts.dev_id 
  where counts.c>0 and counts.c is not null
```

"Distinct"  here need to skip same rows.

Result should be for internal query

```
 dev_id     c
 -----------------
  111           1
```

For all query

```
  user_id       c
 ------------------
   1           1
   2           1
```

If you sure you need also rows  with c=0, then you need do "left join" of fixed_reports2 and large query,that way you will get all rows and rows with c=null will be rows with 0(can be changed by case/when statement)

Comment: I want to get information whether other user has this same dev_id. Then both users get 1. Sadly, this query doesn't work

Comment: Okay, i changed my answer. See it now, and try one-by-one queries to understand why it work that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can get results by doing:

```
select r.user_id, count(*) - 1
from reports r
group by r.user_id;
```

Is this the calculation that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is broken and would not run on many systems. The problem is that the group with `user_id` of 2 has two different `dev_id`s. If you run the "broken query" below you can see that the `min()` and `max()` are distinct but the subquery only sees one of those values which is randomly chosen. The last query is corrected by adding `dev_id` to the groupings which shows you where the "missing" row went in the counts.

```
SELECT -- broken query
    t1.user_id, min(t1.dev_id), max(t1.dev_id),
    (select distinct t1.dev_id from reports) as should_have_errored,
    (SELECT Count(DISTINCT t2.dev_id)
         FROM reports t2
         WHERE t2.user_id != t1.user_id
         AND t2.dev_id = t1.dev_id
    ) AS qu
FROM       reports t1
GROUP BY   t1.user_id;

-- On SQL Server that query returns an error 
-- Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
-- Column 'reports.dev_id' is invalid in the select list because it is
-- not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT -- query that duplicates your original query
    t1.user_id,
    (SELECT Count(DISTINCT t2.dev_id)
         FROM reports t2
         WHERE t2.user_id != t1.user_id
         AND t2.dev_id = max(t1.dev_id) /* <-- see here */
    ) AS qu
FROM       reports t1
GROUP BY   t1.user_id;

SELECT t1.user_id, t1.dev_id, -- fixed query
    (SELECT Count(DISTINCT t2.dev_id)
         FROM reports t2
         WHERE t2.user_id != t1.user_id
         AND t2.dev_id = t1.dev_id
    ) AS qu
FROM       reports t1
GROUP BY   t1.user_id, t1.dev_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6576e3/20

Here are some queries that might be useful:

Which `dev_id`s have multiple `user_id`s associated with them?

```
select dev_id
from reports
group by dev_id
having count(distinct user_id) > 1
```

Which other `user_id`s share a `dev_id` with this `user_id`?

```
select user_id
from reports r1
where exists (
    select 1
    from reports r2
    where r2.dev_id = r1.dev_id and r2.user_id <> ?
)
```

Or really that's just equivalent to an inner join which also makes it easy to list everybody at once. Note that each pair will be listed twice:

```
select r1.user_id, r1.dev_id, r2.user_id as common_user_id
from
    reports r1 inner join reports r2
        on r2.dev_id = r1.dev_id
where
    r1.user_id <> r2.user_id
order by
    r1.user_id, r1.dev_id, r2.user_id
```

And since you've got duplicate rows in your table you'd need to make it `select distinct` to get unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think following sql query should solve you problem:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.dev_id, count(t2.user_id) as qu
FROM (Select Distinct * from reports) t1
Left Join (Select Distinct * from reports)  t2
on t1.user_id != t2.user_id and t2.dev_id = t1.dev_id
group by t1.user_Id, t1.dev_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86d89ff/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, (COUNT(user_id) -1) as qu
FROM reports
GROUP BY user_id
```

This would give desired result in your case, however you can improve it a lot more.
Cheers,,

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    SUM(qu) AS qu
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        count(*)-1 AS qu
    FROM
        reports
    GROUP BY user_id, dev_id
) AS r
GROUP BY user_id
```

No need to do a join if all the data you need is in one table.

Edit: changed the group by to dev_id instead of user_id

Edit2: I think you need both dev_id and user_id in the group by clause.

Edit3: Added a subquery to get the desired result. This might be a little cumbersome, perhaps someone has a way to improve this?

Comment: What would you answer a question with a query where the `select ` clause contains columns that are not in the `group by` clause?  (Note:  I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: Why would you group by dev_id if the query should return data per user_id?

Comment: He wants the number of duplicate dev_id's assigned to each user.
I realise now my answer doesn't fully solve the question.